# Переход внутри приложения

Tags: java, android

Решил попробовать сделать приложение под Android, раньше никогда для телефонов вообще не создавал. Пока-что решил сделать простой браузер, но уже связался с проблемой.

Не работает переход по ссылкам, просит открыть в браузере, хотелось бы, чтобы это всё происходило внутри приложения.
Я не совсем ещё разбираюсь в разработке под Android, так что не ругайтесь, если я туплю.

```
package ru.test.testcomp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* разворачиваем приложение на весь экран */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        /* применяем наш лейаут к текущему экрану */
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* находим WebView элемент по его id */
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);

        /* создаем новые настройки для нашего WebView элемента */
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        /* здесь вы можете поместить URL вашего сайта */
        webView.loadUrl("http://test.ru");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно задать `WebViewClient` и переопределить `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: а могу я как-то сделать, чтобы он вот так летал по ссылкам в определенном домене, а если вдруг домен другой, то запрашивать через браузер?
Типа сайт открывает test1.ru, по сайту может бегать нормально по тем ссылкам, у которых домен test1.ru, а если допустим будет test2.ru, то просить браузер

Comment: @ChipaChop вместо `view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());` можете добавить проверку на домен и в зависимости от него разные действия делать.

Comment: Уф... Учить мне и учить ещё... Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне домен достать? if (webView.getInetAddress() == "http://test.ru"), попробовал так, но getInetAddress выдает ошибку.

Comment: @ChipaChop лучше отдельным вопросом задайте. Ну и да, в Java строки нужно сравнивать, используя `equals()`.